Different Response codes for different sites
So I am making a get request to many websites, but there is a huge problem.
Each website have their own specific code and it is not always 200, for some websites it is 403, 525, etc.
So, how do I know which website will give what response code or do I have to manually save what response code a website will give to the visitor. I have tried to open the network in the developer option but can't understand what is going on.
I have a Json which stores the name and web address of the website, so should I add another key for working_response_code or is there a way to correct the code.
Tried: network in developer option
expecting: something that works [an automated result (optional)]

What? HTTP response codes are very standardized. If you are getting 400s those are client errors (your fault) and if you are getting 500s those are server errors (their fault). What is contained in the body of the response will obviously vary wildly, but only 2xx codes are considered successful.

@CoryKramer I am sending a get request to other website and these were the response code, I could still parse the html and stuff but I am very new to this field, hence I found it quiet difficult to understand why there were different codes.

Those codes are actually a defined standard that most of website respects, you can find a  list here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
Each one has a different meaning, in your case

200 is success, the request has succeed
403 is not authorized

You can get the status code with by accessing the status_code property of the response object

there is nothing mentioned about <Response 525>, the response I am getting. Is it some bug with their website?

any 5xx errors are server side and often not actionable by the caller unfortunately. 525 in particular means "SSL Handshake Failed"
